# How to create about 60 users with installation power in remote linux webserver?

Tags: networking, multi-user, serve

We are about 60 students in our class. Our course teacher provide a remote pc that have public IP. He suggested us to host our web projects on that machine. So, we have to need about 60 user on that machine so that each one can able to access his/her data, modify, remove, install new software etc.

That also be possible making a admin. So that admin can install any software. But problem is when admin have to manage all users requests to installing new software it is burden for admin because man have different choice.

So, we want to make about user so that each user can customize his/her environment easily.

Please give me the idea and solution on this situation.

I will add the system configuration of the machine after knowing from my teacher. As far I know the RAM is 64GB.

Comment: Admin user is always present in every Linux installation - that will be your teacher. To add a user, use `adduser` command: https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-handbook/sect.creating-accounts.en.html

Comment: @rnso Can then each user install software(e.g. `text editor`, `IDE`, etc)

Comment: What is the problem in creating web projects on your own machine and them hosting them on the central server?

Comment: @rnso When we are in lab some of us have not personal laptop to bring in lab, so if the project is created in that machine he/she can access this using the lab pc with remote login.

Comment: @rnso Do you know about `ISPConfig`? https://www.ispconfig.org/

Comment: To avoid extended chat, I have posted the comments in an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Admin user is always present in every Linux installation - that will be your teacher. To add a user, use `adduser` command: https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-handbook/sect.creating-accounts.en.html

To connect, following link may be helpful: https://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/docs/admin-guides/182-how-to-connect-to-access-server-with-linux-clients.html

There should not be any problem in creating web projects on your own machine and them hosting them on the central server.

On Linux desktops, one needs to provide superuser (admin) password to install and remove applications to the system (see https://www.wikihow.com/Install-Software-in-Debian-Linux ). However, one can manually install and run portable applications from one's own home directory (e.g. /home/user_a ).

For portable Linux applications see: https://www.maketecheasier.com/portable-apps-for-linux/ and  https://appimage.org/ . They can be installed and run without need for admin privileges.

ISPconfig ( https://www.ispconfig.org/ ) looks good but I do not have any experience with it. Other similar tools may also be of interest to you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_hosting_control_panels